# OAuth2 With Laravel Passport Give "Auth Error Error: Not Found" On Authorization in L5 Swagger

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui, laravel-passport, darkaonlinel5-swagger

I'm getting "Auth Error Error: Not Found" error when using Autorization in darkaonline/l5-swagger documentation

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORFDT.png)

I'm using PHP v7.4, darkaonline/l5-swagger v7.*, laravel v7.29.

Please let me know if anyone have the solution.

Thanks.

I have did some R&D on the issue and found couple of similar questions with NO answers.

I want to create swagger documentation for APIs with passport authentication.

Comment: Is the auth server at `http://127.0.0.1:8001` actually running? Are there any errors on the Console and Network tabs in the browser dev tools?

Comment: @Helen Yes, the auth server at **http://127.0.0.1:8001** is running. In network tab i get this error "Auth Error Error: Not Found" with status code "404".